# importing PIL image has problems

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to work with Image module in PIL

If I do the following

```
   import PIL
    PIL.Image.open()
```

It says that there is no module named Image.

But the following works fine

```
    from PIL import Image
```

I am using a package and cant change PIL.Image.open()

how to overcome this problem.

Thanks

Comment: is there any way you can change that import? does that pil.image.open() actually work somewhere else? import Image is all you need in your case...

Comment: PIL's namespacing has been screwed up for a while.  You might try taking a look at Pillow which (I believe) fixes some of the import wonkiness, or just do what Samuele Mattiuzzo suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
import PIL.Image
```

is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Duck typing to the rescue. `PIL` doesn't actually have to be a module, it just needs to be an object with the attribute `Image`.

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> class MakePIL(object):
    def __init__(self, Image):
        self.Image = Image

>>> PIL = MakePIL(Image)
>>> PIL.Image
<module 'PIL.Image' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.pyc'>
>>> PIL.Image.open(r'c:\temp\temp.jpg')
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=400x250 at 0x2C88D78>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
from PIL import Image as MyImage
```

and work with MyImage